# sqlPreparedStatement : INSERT INTO if not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I am trying to use preparedStatement to INSERT data only if they not exist in my database but i get an error.

```
#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe près de 'INTO `test` (`id_test`, `name`) VALUES ("1", "TEST")' à la ligne 1
```

Code :

```
SET @preparedStatement = INSERT INTO `test` (`id_test`, `name`) VALUES ("1", "TEST");
PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement;
EXECUTE alterIfNotExists;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;
```

dez

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (The answer may depend on the product used.)

Comment: The syntax should work on mysql and postgresql

Comment: I don't think Postgresql handles those back-ticks very well. And problably wants single quotes for literals. (The ANSI SQL way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the SQL statements `PREPARE`/`EXECUTE` have different syntax in MySQL and PostgreSQL. They are not compatible.

MySQL:

```
SET @preparedStatement =
  'INSERT INTO test (id_test, name, other) VALUES (''1'', ''TEST'', ?)';
PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement;
SET @other = 'STRING'
EXECUTE alterIfNotExists USING @other;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;
```

PostgreSQL:

```
PREPARE alterIfNotExists(text) AS 
  INSERT INTO test (id_test, name, other) VALUES ('1', 'TEST', $1);
EXECUTE alterIfNotExists('STRING');
DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;
```

There are APIs for parameterized queries in every language, and these will be more likely to be compatible between MySQL and PostgreSQL. For example in PHP with PDO, the usage is the same for both databases (and others):

```
<?php

$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
  "INSERT INTO test (id_test, name, other) VALUES ('1', 'TEST', ?)");
$stmt->execute(["STRING"]);
```

---

For the other part of your question, to refrain from inserting if the data is already there, this is also handled differently between MySQL and PostgreSQL.

MySQL:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ...
```

This will just skip the insert if the insert would result in any kind of error.

Alternatively, you can change a row to the current values if a row exists with the values in unique key columns.

```
INSERT INTO test (id_test, name, other) VALUES ('1', 'TEST', ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name), other=VALUES(other);
```

PostgreSQL:

```
INSERT INTO test (id_test, name, other) VALUES ('1', 'TEST', ?)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO test (id_test, name, other) VALUES ('1', 'TEST', ?)
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET ...
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT